# UWP - WebView - Angular JS Injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uwp

I am currently working on UWP application developed on Windows 10.
I am using WebView Control to display 3rd party HTML page.
The HTML was developed using Angular JS.

Issue: The web page has a function `ng-click = c.open();`

I want to override this function using *javascript/angular injection* through my C# code and append `window.external.notify()` so that when the button is clicked on the web page the UWP web view gets notified through `ScriptNotify() event`.

I am new to javascript and angular, any pointers and guidance will be very helpful.

```
 WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
                                           {
                                                   @"(function(){
                                                       var hyperlinks = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');                                        
                                                        for(var i = 0; i < hyperlinks.length; i++)
                                                        {                                                           
                                                            **//What should i place here to override the btn ng-click fucntion??**
                                                        }
                                                    })()"

                                           });
```

Comment: So, what problems have you encountered?

Comment: I am not able to override the ng-click function using javascript via C# code. Attaching the code which i am trying to use in problem statement

Answer (score 1):

> WebView Control to display 3rd party HTML page.

For your requirement, you could inject eval function with `InvokeScriptAsync`, and you could also override btn onclick event handler. But you could not handle angular `$scope` within eval function, because it is blocked in the javaScript. Even if you could get button object and add new even handler, `ng-click` still exist in button function list. the following told how to inject eval and get html element with id.

```
await MyWeb.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
{
       @"(function(){                                          
         document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () {
                    this.innerHTML = 'hello'                   
                }
        })()"

});
```

And you could append `window.external.notify()` in above method, but you it is can't be used to return `$scope` value.